# Filtering a list of url and getting "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

I,m using Selenium to get a list of urls. After I want to filter it for get the ones with certain string but i,m getting and error: `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Code in Python:

```
enlaces = []
for curso in range(2):
   tema = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("user-status-off")
   tema[i].click()
   sleep(2)

   enlace = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
   for links in enlace:
      enlaces.append(links.get_attribute("href"))

   i += 1

filtered_links = [k for k in enlaces if "/o/" in k]
```

If I make `print(enlaces)` i,m getting correct results:

```
https://xxxxxxxxx/portlet-view?page_num=42552006
https://xxxxxxxxx/o/43277208
```

I just want those that contain `/o/` and therefore I use `[k for k in enlaces if "/o/" in k]` . What I,m doing wrong? For getting `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

THANKS

P.D:
Also I tried `list(filter(lambda k: '/o/' in k, enlaces))` and getting the same

Comment: Try running `print('o' in None)` and see what you get. At least one of your items in `enlaces` is `None` and you can't check if a string is `in None`. Either filter out None values before `filtered_links =...` or figure out why some of your items are None in the first place.

Comment: Check if ```k``` is not ```None```. If it is, it can also cause the same error.

Comment: What does `print(type(enlaces))` show.

Comment: What if `links.get_attribute("href")` returns `None`? You haven't guarded for that case.

Comment: The answer of ShadowCooder workd perfects, but I don,t understand why

Comment: The problem is i,m getting `None` for some items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve the problem

```
filtered_links = [k for k in enlaces if k and "/o/" in k]
```

Explanation:
As per the findings of @G.Anderson and @Kenticent, error is shown because value of k is None for some cases. When if k and "/o/" in k is executed if k is None then the second part is not checked

Comment: THANKS, that works perfect. Can u tell me why that works?

Comment: As per the findings of @G.Anderson and @Kenticent, error is shown because value of k is `None` for some cases. When `if k and "/o/" in k` is executed if k is `None` then the second part is not checked

Comment: Ah, now i understand. Thanks